# Pandas - Comparing two Dataframe using sub-string of one Dataframe column

Tags: pandas

I am trying to compare two Dataframes using a sub-string in one column with another Dataframe.

Given below is how my data looks like:

Dataframe 1

```
prod_name, prod_id, prod_category
prod_1, cate_1000101, category_1 
prod_2, cate_123001, category_2
prod_3, cate_900, category_3
prod_4, cate_808, category_4
```

Dataframe 2

```
bill_id, bill_date, prod_ref
101, 2021-01-01, 3001
102, 2021-01-01, 5001
103, 2021-01-01, 8080
```

I am trying to compare if any part of prod_id from Dataframe 1 is available in prod_ref in Dataframe 2

Expected output:

```
prod_name, prod_id, bill_id, bill_date, prod_ref
prod_2, cate_123001, 101, 2021-01-01, 3001
prod_4, cate_808, 103, 2021-01-01, 8080
```

Comment: Is `prod_ref` a string column?

Comment: @DerekO, yes it is of type string

Comment: Is there a limit on how short the substring match should be? Because it seems `prod_ref=5001` could also get matched with any `prod_id` containing `1`, e.g. `prod_id=cate_1000101`

Comment: When you say any part of prod_id, is there a minimum number of digits that you are willing to compare? 808 is in 8080, but the '01' from the end of '123001' is in '3001' and '5001'

Comment: @KevinNash any update on this? even though i'd like to try answering your question, I don't think it's possible until this ambiguity is clarified...

Comment: @DerekO apologies for getting back late on this. I was able to get the desired output as per my output comment below. Appreciate your help on this. Thank you..

Comment: @KevinNash oh nice! when you are able to, you should accept your own answer so that people who have the same question get directed to the right answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the required output using the below

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on = df2.prod_ref.str.extract('(\d+)', expand = False), right_on = df1.prod_id.str.extract('(\d+)', expand = False), how = 'left')
```